# List<Object> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, vector

This is my simple code. I need a clone of the ArrayList listOnayStatu.  GtbEtobsOYenibelge is a entity. But there is a cast problem **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList**. 
Thank you

```
List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge> listOnayStatu = new ArrayList<>();
List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge> cloneOnayStatu;
listOnayStatu = servis.listOnayStatus4Belge(user.getBirimId().getId());
cloneOnayStatu =  ((List) ((ArrayList) listOnayStatu).clone());
```

All code is that.

Comment: This snippet doesn't cause the error you're describing. Can you share a full [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the copy constructor of `ArrayList` which accepts a `Collection<? extends E>`:

```
List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge> listOnayStatu = servis.listOnayStatus4Belge(user.getBirimId().getId());
List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge> cloneOnayStatu = new ArrayList<>(listOnayStatu);
```

That way you create a copy of `listOnayStatu`. Also you should not rely on `clone()` anymore as it has been confirmed to been a bad decision

Answer (score 0):

The method `servis.listOnayStatus4Belge` returns a [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html). A `Vector` implements the `List` interface but is not an `ArrayList`. Therefore you can't cast it to one.

Looking at the problematic statement:

```
cloneOnayStatu =  ((List) ((ArrayList) listOnayStatu).clone());
```

You are copying a Vector and assigning it to `cloneOnayStatu`. You should be able to do it like this:

```
cloneOnayStatu = (List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge>) ((Vector<GtbEtobsOYenibelge>)listOnayStatu).clone();
```

The `clone()` method call will return another Vector but it's declared return type is `Object`. Therefore you need to cast it to a List for the assignment to work.

However, `clone()` is not used much these days. You can have more control over what kind of List you want the result to be by using a constructor, such as the following:

```
cloneOnayStatu = new ArrayList<>(listOnayStatu);
```

Comment: Thank you Klitos but clone() method is not working with list.

Comment: when listOnayStatu is updated, cloneOnayStatu is update in same time.I want cloneOnayStatu has previous size of listOnayStatu when it is updated.

Comment: Both the `clone()` method and the `new ArrayList<>()` constructor create copies which are _not_ updated when the original is updated. However, note that these copies are simply copies of the _references_. If the referenced objects are themselves updated, then both lists will see the update, because the elements of both lists refer to the same object. Perhaps you want a deep copy. For that, you will need to iterate over all the elements and create a copy of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save it as a new arraylist.

```
List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge> listOnayStatu = new ArrayList<>();
List<GtbEtobsOYenibelge> cloneOnayStatu;
listOnayStatu = servis.listOnayStatus4Belge(user.getBirimId().getId());
cloneOnayStatu =  new ArrayList(listOnayStatu);
```

or you can use addAll

```
cloneOnayStatu.addAll(listOnayStatu);
```